# Mcafee Manual Classification - Suppress Alert Message in a directory

Tags: data-loss, mcafee

I'm sorry for the English, I'm Brazilian. I am developing an application for a client. The client uses Mcafe DLP. However, **in a specific folder** that our system executes, it would be necessary to **put in an exception list** ***all files*** or ***at least the xls and xlsx files*.**

A message similar to this:

[Click here to view the message - Mcafee Manual Classification Alert Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbEWD.png)

At all times, our program needs to manipulate the files in this folder and this message prevents the normal flow of the system. The client thinks it's a system error, but I'm trying to show him that it's a question of configuring Mcafee.

Is it possible to suppress this message? Please, could you tell me where you have a step by step with screens showing how it can be done?

So that I can pass it on to my client and he decides how to do it...

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: You can *suppress* it by having your client exclude the folder. You can't bypass it programmatically - if you could do so, so could any malware, which would defeat the entire purpose of using AV software at all.

Comment: Thank you very much @KenWhite! Could you send me some screens to show this customer where he should go and what he should do? As I told him, I believe that if I were to develop a mechanism for sending keys and mouse clicks, it would be similar to malware and the tool itself must protect itself from something like this. My application needs to generate xls or xlsx files in a folder and send them by email. There, this "Manual Classification" alert appears and waits for the user to click to proceed with the flow. And it should be running in the background automatically.

Comment: Um, no. I can't send you *screens* or anything else. You or your client can read the McAfee documentation to find out how to do this.  I think you're correct that the tool would detect your efforts to bypass it. Have you reached out to McAfee support to ask them about the configuration you need?

Comment: I understand @KenWhite. You have already helped by saying that there is an option to do this. However, my client is very resistant to help, thinking that the mistake is on our side. I couldn't find the documentation, mainly about this part related to something like "list of exceptions". Do you indicate a link?